# Callback for hash property access in perl

Tags: perl, perl-hash

Is there any native way in Perl to know what key of a hash was accessed?
Something like magic methods that exist in some languages or like a proxy object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is. It's called "tying" a variable.

[`tie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) is a combination of instantiating a proxy object (from a specified class) and binding it to a variable.

See [`perldoc perltie`](https://metacpan.org/pod/perltie) for details.

The short version is:

```
tie %hash, 'Some::Class';
```

And then accessing `%hash` will trigger method calls in `Some::Class` (provided it implements a `TIEHASH` constructor and the rest of the interface).

Comment: I think this really needs an example, or at least a reference to [`Tie::Hash`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/Hash.html), from which a basic hash interface can be built.

Answer (score 2):

Perl allows you to [`tie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/tie.html) a variable to a class.  This provides a mechanism to inject your custom code (the code of your tied class) into various operations that can be enacted on the tied variable.  For a hash, those operations are `TIEHASH`, `STORE`, `FIRSTKEY`, `FETCH`, `NEXTKEY`, `EXISTS`, `DELETE`, `CLEAR`, and `SCALAR`.

A complete implementation of a tied hash, therefore, would implement each of those methods.  To make this easier, the core Perl distribution provides the module [`Tie::Hash`](https://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/Hash.html), which also provides `Tie::StdHash`.

`Tie::StdHash` is probably the shortest path to adding some functionality to an otherwise rather typical hash implementation, as it provides standard implementations of each of the hash methods mentioned above.  To add your own functionality you can just override those methods for which it makes sense to do so. Then either call out to `SUPER::*` (where * represents the name of the overridden operation) or provide the desired hash functionality in its entirety in the overridden method.  An example is probably simpler than words:

```
package NoisyHash;

use strict;
use warnings;

require Tie::Hash;
our @ISA = q(Tie::StdHash);

sub STORE {
    my ($self, $key, $value) = @_;
    warn "\tSet $key to $value\n";
    return $self->SUPER::STORE($key, $value);
}

sub FETCH {
    my ($self, $key) = @_;
    warn "\tFetch from $key\n";
    return $self->SUPER::FETCH($key);
}

1;


package main;

use strict;
use warnings;

tie my %hash, 'NoisyHash';

$hash{A} = 1;
$hash{B} = 'foo';

print "\$hash{A} = $hash{A}\n";
print "\$hash{B} = $hash{B}\n";
```

In this example, the `FETCH` and `STORE` methods are overridden with code that causes them to spit out some diagnostics to `STDERR`.  And then we retain regular hash semantics for those methods by finally calling out to `SUPER::*`.  We could trivially have just implemented our own versions of that functionality rather than calling SUPER, but leveraging an existing implementation is less error prone.

The output from the preceding example is:

```
    Set A to 1
    Set B to foo
    Fetch from A
$hash{A} = 1
    Fetch from B
$hash{B} = foo
```

As shown in the example, the `tie` function is used to bind `NoisyHash` to `%hash`.  It turns out that `tie` also returns an object, which isn't often used, but could be used to provide additional methods that may be invoked against the hash that aren't part of the default set of hash operations listed above.

```
package SumHash;

use strict;
use warnings;

require Tie::Hash;
our @ISA = q(Tie::StdHash);
use List::Util;

sub sum {
    my $self = shift;
    return List::Util::sum(values %$self);
}

1;

package main;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $hash_obj = tie my %hash, 'SumHash';

@hash{qw(a b c d e)} = (1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

my $sum = $hash_obj->sum;
print "Sum of (",
      join(', ', values %hash),
      ") is $sum.\n",
```

Example output from this code is:

```
Sum of (3, 4, 1, 5, 2) is 15.
```

So here we're calling a `sum` method that we've placed in the `SumHash` class. The class still inherits from `Tie::StdHash`, and doesn't override any standard methods, so it still retains standard hash functionality.  But it does add the ability to tally the hash's values.  However, this is not the easiest way to tally a hash's values.  Rather than going through all the trouble of tying a hash just to add summation to it, one could just do this:

```
use List::Util qw(sum);
print "Sum of (", join(', ', values %hash), ") is ", sum(values %hash), "\n";
```

This exemplifies why there is a general sense in the Perl community that tying variables is rarely the best approach to solving typical problems.  Tying variables creates hard to follow and reason about action at a distance.  And tied variables have considerably worse performance.  But the practice does have occasionally justifiable uses, and Perl provides a means.

See `perldoc Tie::Hash` for an explanation of that module. And be aware that `tie` may be used to tie any of Perl's common containers: a scalar, an array, a hash, or a filehandle.

The most exhaustive explanation within Perl's documentation for using `tie` is available at [`perldoc perltie`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perltie.html)